# Setting default install locations in CMake

Tags: cmake

How do I make CMake automatically install any library added with add_library (or binary with add_executable) to folders I specify? I'd like to tell it to "install every (shared) archive to lib" and "install every executable to bin", for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just set EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH and LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH.  These and more common variables are documented here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: No, that's not a solution. I don't wish to build as root every time. I want to install them in a location, not build them in that location.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  Sorry about that.  How about either CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX or the stuff at the bottom of this page, then: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Install_Commands

Comment: The prefix comes close, but I'd like to put all my libraries in, for example, {prefix}/lib/{our project name}-{ ... and version}/. Ergo, the prefix only won't do.

Comment: So how about the formulation of install() at the bottom of that "Install Commands" page I just linked?  It seems like it will do what you want if you're willing to mention all your install() targets.

Comment: Nah, that's the other part: I don't wish to name every library/target/whatever. I just want to say "All the ARCHIVEs go here, all the SHARED go there" etc. An install(TARGETS *) if you will.

Comment: Well I am afraid there is no such thing.